# To move my question to English Language & Usage

Tags: support, questions

I asked this one

> [Is it OK to use "otherwise" after "where"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/251208/is-it-ok-to-use-otherwise-after-where)

question assuming it will be very easy and straightforward to answer. That is, a typical question from a foreign person who don't really know the language. As I see now, this question is much less straightforward as I thought, and it will be much better to have it on https://english.stackexchange.com/.

Can we move it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Done

You can find it here:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/538314/is-it-ok-to-use-otherwise-after-where

Thanks for the request! Also as a general reminder this is the right way to do it if you feel another site might be better suited to your question, as opposed to cross-posting on multiple sites.